# Why Sapper omits clossing HTML tags?

Tags: svelte, sapper

When I clone the [official Sapper template](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template), install dependencies and export it

```
~$ degit "sveltejs/sapper-template#webpack" sapper-template
~$ cd sapper-template/
~/sapper-template$ npm install
~/sapper-template$ npm run export
```

and then inspect the generated index.html, the closing `</body>` and `</html>` tags are absent.

```html
...
<body>
    ...
    <script src=/client/4def89e12e93fe68fd0d/main.js> </script>
// EOF
```

Why does Sapper generate formally invalid HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been discussed on the sapper repository here: :https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/1061

In that issue there is a link to the HTML standard about tag emissions: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission

The conclusion is that, while it might *look* strange, it's a perfectly valid html

Comment: Thanks for showing me the quirks of html standard. .) It makes sense.